# How do you get $(n-1)! \over n!$ from $1 \over n$

Tags: probability

This is from problem 2.30 in Introduction to Probability, 2nd Edition by Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis.

[image: problem]

[image: solution]

How does the solution get $(n-1)! \over n!$ from $1 \over n$?

Similarly, how does the solution get $1 - e^{-1}$ from the final sequence?

Comment: $n-1)!$ is the product of the $n-1$ first natural numbers, $n!$ of the $n$ first. The differ by the last factor, $n$. Enters the usual rule for simplifying fractions.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that by definition

$$\frac{(n-1)!}{  n!}=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)\ldots2\cdot 1}{  n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots2\cdot 1}$$

For your second question refer to [Botond's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2968045/505767).

Comment: It's good to see you back!

Comment: @Botond Thanks a lot! Bye

Answer (score 1):

It is $$n!=(n-1)!n$$ and this solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

For your second question:
$$e^x=\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
And substitute in $x=-1$.